# Retrieving downloaded link names using jSoup

Tags: java, hyperlink, jsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the names of .zip files that are available for download. Referencing the jSoup "cookbook", I've found that the example uses *"%s (%s)"*, which returns *hyperlink (download name)*. I only want the latter part, but am having difficulty differentiating the two. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void getNames() throws IOException{

    String url = "http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=d855";
    print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a");

    downloadNames = new ArrayList<>();

    // print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
    for (Element link : links) {
        downloadNames.add(print("<%s> (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35)));
    }

    int x = 0;
    while (x < downloadNames.size()) {

        // System.out.println(downloadNames.get(x));
        x++;

    }

    uniqueDownloadNames = new ArrayList<>();


    int y = 0;
    while (y < downloadNames.size()) {

        if (downloadNames.get(y).contains(".zip") && downloadNames.get(y).startsWith("<http://download")) {
            uniqueDownloadNames.add(downloadNames.get(y));
        }
        y++;

    }
    int z = 0;
    while (z < uniqueDownloadNames.size()) {

        System.out.println(uniqueDownloadNames.get(z));
        z++;

    }

}

private static String print(String msg, Object... args) {
    // System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    String s = String.format(msg, args);
    return s;
}

private static String trim(String s, int width) {
    if (s.length() > width)
        return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
    else
        return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve by 2 last loops in `getNames()` method. You can simply get rid of duplicated entries by using Set instead of List. HashSet, implementation of a Set interface, stores only unique entries. So your `getNames()` would become much shorter. Plus I modified it also to retrieve only the second part.

```
public static void getNames() throws IOException {

    String url = "http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=d855";
    print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a");

    Set<String> downloadNames = new HashSet<>();

    // print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
    for (Element link : links) {
        downloadNames.add(print("(%s)", trim(link.text(), 35)));
    }

    for (String element : downloadNames) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }

}
```

Few tips:

- please look at my iterating loop, please use it in the future. While loop has a bit different purpose.
- the error in your version was probably in this if:

`if (downloadNames.get(y).contains(".zip") && downloadNames.get(y).startsWith("<http://download")) {`

You checked if the name starts with `<http://download`, however I assume you deleted that part from your string earlier. That is the reason output was empty, because no string passed this test.